# Prevent user to overwrite files and directories

Tags: linux, security, filesystems, file-permissions, access-control-list

Help me to learn if this scenario is doable using Linux. I want to secure the access to a system path called "/mnt/data".

System users retrictions:

- 'daemon_user': read/write access.
- 'read_user': only read.
- 'appender_user': add files but **NOT** delete or overwrite existing ones.

'daemon_user' constantly creates new files so the "do not delete/overwrite" restriction has to apply for the new files created as well.

*Note: Initially I discard to use 'chattr' since that applies to all users, including root. I don't want that level of restriction.*

Comment: Could you describe the real problem? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Sure, I want to prevent "appender_user" to be able to replace files at /mnt/data". /mnt/data" files are created and used by "daemon_user" and if "appender_user" gets to replace a single file we potentially lose data.

Comment: What are your requirements for performance and POSIX compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement daemon_user and read_user with POSIX extended ACLs (getfacl, setfacl, chmod, chown). For appender_user you can use append attribute (`chattr +a filename`, lsattr), but this would limit for all users.

Another way to implement this is to use a service that limits the access to those files. E.g. you share the files with [samba](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs#Samba_Extended_ACL_Support) and you use Windows ACLs that have append only attribute.

Another way to implement appender_user is to create a SELinux targeted policy. See how `httpd_sys_ra_content_t` was implemented.

Comment: "For appender_user you can use append attribute (chattr +a filename, lsattr), but this would limit for all users." -> tested this but it's too much restrictive, it affects the "daemon_user" and the setup doesn't work.

Comment: You might need to write a SELinux policy to achieve this.